# tomcat7 web manager application url not working

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I would need experts advice on tomcat7 issue I am facing now while installing it on ubuntu 14.04.

I have tomcat7 installed and I am able to see http://localhost:8080 index html page of tomcat7.

But when I try to access http://localhost:8080/manager/html, I keep getting constantly asked to enter the username and password even though the username and password are correctly set in tomcat-users.xml file.

contents of /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml file as below

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-         
gui"/>

-->
</tomcat-users>
```

please help me !!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the all of the tomcat users are commented out by `<!- -->`.
Remove those lines and try again, like this:

```
<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```